# Redirect users based on PC and iPhone

Tags: html, redirect

I faced a problem when trying to redirect users based on whether they use a PC or an iPhone. The following scripts can be used to redirect users:

**PC**

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.google.com">
```

**iPhone**

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {

        if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) {

            window.location = "http://yahoo.com";       

        }
}
```

I used Google and Yahoo as an example.

However, when I'm using both scripts at once, when I visit the page on the iPhone it keeps reloading (ending up in a loop it seems). When I go to the page with my computer, it redirects me as it should. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Android/i) ) {
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) {
            window.location = "http://yahoo.com";       
        }
} 
//PC
else {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
}
```

Comment: Used that code, but it still won't work. But I guess I know why. What I'm building is a mobile version of an existing website which isn't mine (for a school project). So that whenever someone with a smartphone visits my url, they will see my url which is a mobile version. But if someone with a computer visits my url, they will be redirected to the existing website. Is this even possible to accomplish?

To simplify it:

My URL is [a], the existing website is [b].

Smartphone visits [a] --> stay on [a].
Computer visits [a] --> redirect to [b].

Comment: How Are you going to modify the website to redirect?  Injecting or cross scripting?  (Depends) You have to update the HTML to do that and you need access to it.  Otherwise, everyone will be redirecting other websites to their website.  You can get the source code of the HTML and use that, but that will be static.